# Deleted Login Ip Range from a change set?

Tags: force.com, change-set

I did a change set this weekend, and in the logs there's one line in the audit trail that has me worried. `Deleted Login Ip Range from System Administrator` This wasn't part of the change set, and I do not know how/ what to make of it.

Any idea on what could have caused this to end up in production??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change sets are non-destructive, so I wonder if this wasn't an opportunistic update of login ip ranges by sf themselves?

Answer (score 6):

While I thought that Change Sets could not be destructive, I just pushed a change set yesterday that removed a login IP restriction from a profile. I'm logging this with support as I feel this is a bug.

UPDATE:
I spoke to the PM for Change Sets today and he confirmed it is working as designed. It is even [documented](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=changesets_perm_sets_profiles.htm&language=en_US), but I don't really think it is very clear. He also noted that after the Winter release, even more changes will be pushed when you include a profile in a change set. These include user perms (manage users, modify all data, etc).

Just wrote a blog post on this topic: http://wp.me/p3elao-ae

Comment: After a Twitter conversation, it sounds like others have had the same issue: https://twitter.com/dhoechst/status/385776870291030016

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know you can't do any destructive changes with Change Sets, meaning you can't remove data (especially records in the DB), can't revoke access, remove permissions, in short you can't do anything destructive from change sets.

So my guess is that somehow the IP Range set got manually altered.

Comment: Correct, Change Sets are non-destructive.

Comment: can you overwrite the IP Ranges in this scenerio